# IntelliJ can't display big file?

Tags: intellij-idea

My text file is 1.58G, my IntelliJ custom VM options is set as "-Xmx4G". Why does it shows

```
"The file is too large; 1.58G. Showing a read-only of the first 2.56M".
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`idea.properties` file [contains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869) the default limits for the files IntelliJ IDEA can handle:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Maximum file size (kilobytes) IDE should provide code assistance for.
# The larger file is the slower its editor works and higher overall system memory requirements are
# if code assistance is enabled. Remove this property or set to very large number if you need
# code assistance for any files available regardless their size.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Maximum file size (kilobytes) IDE is able to open.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.max.content.load.filesize=20000
```

These can be changed using `Help` | **Edit Custom Properties**.

Comment: What does this mean? "The file size (35B) exceeds configured limit (1734967296B). Code insight features are not available"

Comment: I have these two: idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500000 & idea.max.content.load.filesize=2000000

Comment: Try `idea.max.content.load.filesize=0` to use the max possible value.

Comment: Do you need to restart IDEA after updating these?

Comment: @MattG yes, IDE restart required.