# android studio cannot build and run the project The file is too large

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, imageview, android-studio-3.0

My app is for view images When user click on next button show next image or back button show the previous image, the problem started When I tried to run the project I see some error about images size

> "The file is too large; 80.83M. Showing a read-only of the first 2.56M".

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681019/intellij-cant-display-big-file) the privous message is disappered but I still see some errors

```
Error:error: failed to read data meta data.
Error:failed parsing overlays.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

**The first error**

[image]

**The second error**

[image]

Comment: set android:largeHeap="true" Under Application tag in manifest file

Comment: @abhilash-maurya Unfortunately this not working for me, the same errors

Comment: Clean your project and then rebuild it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Write `android:largeHeap="true"` in your manifest under application.

2) Go to File -> Invalidate caches/restart -> Just restart. This will clear all caches.

3) Go to Build -> Clean project

4) Go to Build -> Rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a PNG this big? A good practice is to keep your APK size as small as possible, with a reasonable size for an app like yours around 4MB. Even if you crunch these PNG images they will still be way too big and result in a huge size of your APK.

According to the Android Developers' guide:

> Users often avoid downloading apps that seem too large, particularly
>   in emerging markets where devices connect to often-spotty 2G and 3G
>   networks or work on pay-by-the-byte plans.

More info: [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html)

Comment: thank you for information, but this app is for education purpose, in the real project I'll use JPEG instead of PN